# Book that involves a mom and her son teaming up with the son's father, who was disowned right before the son's birth

Tags: story-identification, books, space

The mom and son are in the same division of a space federation and, after a war breaks out, they are ordered by the higher ups to work with a pirate group that was hired to work with them. The father turns out to be the representative, and there is a lot of bad blood between the two at first.

The father was disowned because he had to leave the mom at the altar by cheating on her, because people threatened his brother's life. After his disownment, the father was sold into slavery and then bought by the pirates, which is how he began working for them. They tried to kill him using an experimental procedure no one had survived before, by wiring his nervous system to the space ship's controls, which gave him a massive advantage during all space-fights that he was involved with.

The mom had a very memorable surname, but of course I forgot every name in the book. The son and the father were also amazing at the fight rings held on their homeworld. I read it a few years ago, at least 4, maybe 5, and the cover was like a deep blue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I red it a few years ago, at least 4, maybe 5 and the cover was like a deep blue but other than that I don't remember anything unfortunately sorry.

Comment: One of Sherrilyn Kenyon's "League" books?https://www.fantasticfiction.com/k/sherrilyn-kenyon/league-nemesis-rising/